# Replace a part in a table n times by adding the previus values of each iteration and substructing the initial value

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have the following Nested table

```
 (myinputmatrix = Table[Nest[function, myinputmatrix[[i]][[j]], 
 myinputmatrix[[i]][[j]][[2]][[2]] + 
  myinputmatrix[[i]][[j]][[3]][[2]]], {i, 
 Dimensions[myinputmatrix][[1]]}, {j, 
 Dimensions[myinputmatrix][[2]]}]) // TableForm

fq[k_?NumericQ] := Count[RandomReal[{0, 1}, k], x_ /; x < .1]

 function[x_List] :=  ReplacePart[
 x, {{2, 1} -> x[[2]][[1]] - #1,
```

**{2, 2} ->   x[[2]][[2]] + #1**,

```
{3, 1} -> x[[3]][[1]] - #2, {3, 2} -> 
   x[[3]][[2]] + #2}] &[fq[x[[2]][[1]]], fq[x[[2]][[1]]]];
```

My problem is that I want to add only the *#1* in the bold part above, but not only the new one, I want it to add all *#1* for the n times (Nest function times]

If I try the function

```
 function[x_List] :=  ReplacePart[
 x, {{2, 1} -> x[[2]][[1]] - #1, {2, 2} ->   #1,
  {3, 1} -> x[[3]][[1]] - #2, {3, 2} ->  #2}] &[fq[x[[2]][[1]]],
 fq[x[[2]][[1]]]];
```

I am having as a result the last value of fq[k]. I thought of replacing that part in my table with 0 but is not going to work since I am using it in my nested list, also I thought of substricting that part from my initial table but I am not sure which way is the best to do it and if the way I am thinking is the correct one. Can anyone help me?

Comment: I just want to draw your attention to the fact that `fq[k]` generates a random variate from `BinomialDistribution[k, 1/10]`, just in a very inefficient way. So you can replace `fq` with `fq[k_]:=RandomVariate[BinomialDistribution[k,.1]]`

Comment: @Sasha I have done fq to generate the number of times that I have random number <0.1 for k times, by changing it with your suggestion I am going to have the same result?

Comment: Your implementation of `fq` simulates a random variate by some procedure. I claim that this random variate has the same probability distribution as `BinomialDistribution[k, 0.1]`. Indeed you can convince yourself of this by evaluating `DistributionFitTest[Table[fq[10], {10^4}], 
 BinomialDistribution[10, 0.1]]` in v8. If you will ultimately average over this random variate (i.e. compute expectation), then you can replace your `fq` with any other code that gives the same distribution

Comment: @Sasha thank you very much, I will check that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I may restate the problem and hopefully clarify the question for myself. At each iteration in the `Nest`, you want to add not the current (random) output from `fq`, but the cumulation of the current and all past values of it. But because the random output depends at each iteration on the input matrix, you need to calculate both the random number and the current value of the matrix in the same iteration.
If that hadn't been true you could use `Fold`.

Restating `fq` as Sasha suggested **EDIT** with some type checking to avoid problems with incorrect input:

```
fq[k_Integer?Positive]:=RandomVariate[BinomialDistribution[k,.1]]
```

You might want to add some other error checking code. Something like this, depending on your requirements, might do.

```
fq[0]:= 0;
fq[k_Real?Positive]:=RandomVariate[BinomialDistribution[Round[k],.1]]
```

You need `function` to take the random numbers as parameters. **EDIT 1 and 2** I have changed the syntax of this function to use the parameters explicitly instead of the original question's anonymous function within a function. This should avoid some syntax errors. Also note that I have used "`NumericQ`" rather than "`Real`" as the type for the `rv1` and `rv2` parameters, because they can be integers at the start of the `Nest` iteration.

```
function[x_List, rv1_?NumericQ, rv2_?NumericQ] :=  ReplacePart[
 x, {{2, 1} -> x[[2]][[1]] - rv1, {2, 2} ->   rv1,
 {3, 1} -> x[[3]][[1]] - rv2, {3, 2} ->  rv2}]
```

And then pass the current random number as a local constant using `With` to a `Nest` function that works on a list containing your matrix *and* the cumulation of the random variates. I have used `myoutputmatrix` because I really don't like the idea of rewriting existing expressions all the time. That's just me. Now, the one other thing is that you need to set `n`, the number of iterates. I've set it to 5 but you can make this a parameter in a function if you want (see below).

```
(myoutputmatrix = Table[ First[Nest[With[{rv=fq[#1[[1]][[2]][[1]] ]}, 
{function[#1[[1]],rv, rv+#1[[2]] ],rv+#1[[2]] }]&, 
 { myinputmatrix[[i]][[j]], 0 }, 5]],
 {i,  Dimensions[myinputmatrix][[1]]}, {j, 
 Dimensions[myinputmatrix][[2]]}]) // TableForm
```

The `First` is there because in the end you only want the matrix, not the cumulation of the random variates.

```
outputmatrix[input_List, n_Integer?Positive] /; 
  Length[Dimensions[input]] == 4 := 
  Table[First[
   Nest[With[{rv = fq[#1[[1]][[2]][[1]]]}, {function[#1[[1]], rv, 
    rv + #1[[2]]], rv + #1[[2]]}] &, {input[[i]][[j]], 0}, n]],
    {i, Dimensions[input][[1]]}, {j, Dimensions[input][[2]]}]

outputmatrix[myinputmatrix, 10] // TableForm
```

**EDIT** I have checked this now and it runs, but note that you can get negative numbers in the output, which is not what you want, I don't think.

Comment: Thanks for your respond. There are some syntax error as you said there might be and I cannot correct then even that I try. Can you please try to fix them?. By the way If I understand correctly what you said in the text I think that this is what I need.

Comment: noni - Sorry about that. Put each of the three bits of code I provided into separate cells of the notebook and evaluate them in order. Which cell is giving the syntax error? What is the error message? Is it an orange cell bracket or something else? I'm at work now, with no Mathematica installation handy, so it's hard to work out the problem without that information. I could look at it tonight, but we have a house guest arriving.

Comment: the error is in the last bit where myinputmatrix is being evalueted. The problem is the brackets but by correcting what I think is the problem is giving me more errors. I am sending you a picture of it, maybe is better than my english :P

Comment: I cannot upload the image sorry. I have it in my google doc account [image](https://docs.google.com/document/d/18J2xpxGN--105UQpFmhEj6Dl3K5iZbUiGwo85S3gY5o/edit?hl=en_GB) It is not nessesary to check it if you don't want me to learn your email. Sorry about that.

Comment: Try now - I think I found the error in the With[{},... ] section. Normally I use the special double brackets for list parts, so I pick up when I've missed a closing square bracket.

Comment: It giving me errors again, the error says that BinomialDistribution::nnintprm: "Parameter BinomialDistribution[BinomialDistribution[BinomialDistribution[BinomialDistribution[BinomialDistribution[BinomialDistribution[BinomialDistribution[BinomialDistribution[BinomialDistribution[<<2>>],0.1],0.1],0.1],0.1],0.1],0.1],0.1],0.1] at position 1 in BinomialDistribution[BinomialDistribution[BinomialDistribution[BinomialDistribution[BinomialDistribution[BinomialDistribution[<<2>>],0.1],0.1],0.1],0.1],0.1],0.1],0.1],0.1] is expected to be a non-negative integer." But fq by itself is working fine

Comment: That's because the input (part [[2,1]] of the matrix) is either zero or otherwise not a positive integer. I've changed the definition of fq to check for this. You will need to Clear[fq] first then define it the way I have with the _Integer?Positive check, so you can see what the issue is. But it tells me that the rest of the code is working. I'll add another couple of definitions of fq to handle this.

Comment: now the error is this one Part::partd: Part specification 1[[1]] is longer than depth of object. >>

Comment: and by using the seconf fq it is not working but it it not fiving me errors, is giving me as a result function[function[function[function[.....